# Passing an arrayList between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'll start off by saying that when It comes to passing arrays between forms Im very new to this concept.

Currently I have the sollowing situation:

1. a users clicks a buttons which produces a gridview showing user details
2. the user can click a cell which will in turn add the data to a textbox and to an array list
3. The user then clicks a button to return to the previous form where the array list elements are accessed and displayed within a textbox on the first form.

Currently I have created a new construtor for my first form (Form1) that should set the declared arrayList from the second form.

At the moment im getting no error but a blank form is simply produced. The following screenshots will show the situation:

The users clicks the 'Add' button of the first form - Form1

[image]

The user then selects the 'email' cell which places the address into the textbox. This email address is also added to a list array in the background code.

[image]

When 'Add Contacts' is clicked **the first form should be displayed (the one in the first picture) but instead a new one is produced:**

[image]

Here is the code. I currently believe this issue lies with my second constructor in my Form1 class that is used to set the returned array List:

```
   List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();

   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        string add = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        myCollection.Add(add);

        txtCCAdd.Text += add + ", ";

    }



 private void btnSetCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1(myCollection);
        form.Show();
    }
```

Form1 constructor used to set the List:

```
    string attachment;
    List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    **** Second constructor used to set the List array ****
    public Form1(List<string> a)
    {
        myCollection = a;
    }
```

Hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you never actually initialise any controls, thus the form is never actually created. use:

```
public Form1(List<string> a)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myCollection = a;
}
```

or

```
public Form1(List<string> a)
{
    Form1();
    myCollection = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing list and creating new *Form1*, just return selected value from second form:

In *Form1* (when you need to show *Form2*):

```
using(Form2 form2 = new Form2())
{
   if (form2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
      return;

   myCollection.Add(form2.SelectedValue); // add value to list here
}
```

In *Form2*:

```
public string SelectedValue { get; private set; }

void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedValue = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}

private void btnSetCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Even if you want to return several selected values from *Form2*, then use local list of values, and return that list to *Form1*. *Form2* should not know anything about how you are going to use those values. Think about `FileOpenDialog`. It just returns selected file name, that is responsibility of that dialog. You don't need to pass some list or object to be filled by `FileOpenDialog`.

Comment: +1 a was answering the same when I have seen your answer, this is the logical thing to do

Comment: @Steve thanks, and agree. Instead of passing whole data between forms it always better to work with subset of data (single responsibility)

Answer (score 0):

Call InitializeComponent in your second constructor.